# A datetime arithmetic in MQL4

Tags: datetime, duration, mql4

I would like to define a `datetime` type variable that is a result of a simple arithmetic operation between `datetime` type variables.

I've defined:

```
datetime duration = ( TimeCurrent() - OrderOpenTime() );
datetime   TmStop = StringToTime( "1970.01.01 16:00" );
```

but when I call it in some other arithmetic operation or generally in code like this

```
ExitBuy_H1 = ( duration > TmClose && ...
```

or this

```
text[3]= "Duration: " + TimeToStr( duration, TIME_MINUTES );
```

it doesn't work.

`TmStop` instead works fine.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime` is a simple integer, number of seconds passed since `1970.01.01 00:00`. `duration` in your example is also in seconds, even though it is `datetime` formated, when you need it in minutes, divide by 60. `TmClose` from your example means `16*60*60 seconds` and you can compare that integer with any other `int` of course, but what might be the reason for that? 
if you hold you position more then 16 hours, then duration > TmClose is true. if you want to convert difference in seconds (duration) into time, then you will have time converted from 1970.01.01 00:00 + duration seconds.

Anyway it is not clear what is your goal in doing this calculations? if you want to make sure that you hold that particular position more then x hours, then simple `bool holdMoreThanXHours = TimeCurrent()-OrderOpenTime()>x*PeriodSeconds(PERIOD_H1)`, and do not forget to reselect each ticket if you have several ones in open

Comment: `ExitBuy_H1= (duration > TmClose) `
stands for "when the position is open from more than TmClose, close it".



If I wrote  `ExitBuy_H1= ((TimeCurrent() - OrderOpenTime()) > TmClose` works,


if I wrote  `ExitBuy_H1= duration > TmClose` 
doesen't works

Comment: maybe you dont assign some value to duration before, it must work, they all are integers in MQL4

Comment: i just wrote

`datetime duration = (TimeCurrent() - OrderOpenTime()); 
datetime TmStop = StringToTime ("1970.01.01 16:00");
ExitBuy_H1= (duration> TmStop);`

and it doesen't works...can't understand why...

Comment: really no idea what is your goal. TmClose should be in seconds, converting it to datetime looks strange. Make sure your orderOpenTime() returns a value not an error

Comment: I only want to call a datetime variable datetime `duration = (TimeCurrent() - OrderOpenTime());` that let me close a position hold for more than n hours.

If, in the corner info, I write `text[3]= "Duration: " + TimeToStr(duration, TIME_MINUTES);` it also doesen't works, it works with every other entry (i.e. TimeCurrent(), OrderOpenTime(), TimeCurrent() - OrderOpenTime(), TmStop, ecc) except duration (as defined as above)...can't explain why...

Comment: because your parameters are both converted into seconds since 1970.01.01, after you compute duration - i think it is some number of seconds, see my example above with bool holdMoreThanXHours, if you want to see how long does your position is open, write `text="Duration: "+(string)(duration/PeriodSeconds(PERIOD_M1));`

Answer (score 1):

### Fact A)  the code, as-is, absolutely out of any question works.

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                           Test_StackOverflow.mq4 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property strict

void OnStart() {
     datetime duration = ( TimeCurrent() - OrderOpenTime() );
     string        txt = "Duration: " + TimeToStr( duration, TIME_MINUTES );
     }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

> `0 error(s), 0 warning(s), compile time: 2000 msec       1   1`

---

### Fact B) the full `MCVE`-context of the code, as-is, is missing.

StackOverflow requires users to post a complete MCVE-representation of the problem. This requirement was not met in the original post.

While the **`datetime`** and **`int`** data-types are mutually interchangeable, the problem does not seem to be hidden in this intrinsic "duality" of a value representation, but must be somewhere else.

The main suspects for ***Why?*** are:

- variable definition was **masked** by another variable having the same name
- variable scope-of-definition was **exceeded** ( asking a variable outside of it's scope )
- db.Pool-operations were  **not** preceded by **`OrderSelect()`**